# Why I get unread block data - Illegal State Exception?

Tags: exception, apache-spark

I only have the following:

```
JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> dataRDD = jsc
            .newAPIHadoopRDD(
                    hbase_conf,
                    TableInputFormat.class,
                    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable.class,
                    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result.class);

sparkConf.log().info("Count of data = "+String.valueOf(dataRDD.count()));
```

I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, server-name): java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data
    java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectInputStream.java:2394)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find some hints here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1867
Some pepole replaced hadoop-client with hadoop-common libs. Your case seems similar to mine where it needs proper hbase jars. I added `hbase/hbase-0.98.12/lib/*` to `spark.executor.extraClasspath` and it went away. Here's another way to set this jar. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spark-users/gXSfbjauAjo